# How to search for multiple nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to match multiple nodes but i cant create the correct query.

This query works for david, but how can i add another name after david? such as john?

```
Match (p:People {peopleName:"david"})-[:PEOPLE_ASSOCIATED_PLACE]-(pl:Place)-[:PLACE_ASSOCIATED_EVENT]-(e:Event)  
return p.peopleName, pl.placeName, e.eventTitle, e.eventDate order by e.eventDate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use the WHERE clause much like SQL

```
MATCH (p:People)-[:PEOPLE_ASSOCIATED_PLACE]-(pl:Place)-[:PLACE_ASSOCIATED_EVENT]-(e:Event) 
WHERE p.peopleName in ["david", "John"]
RETURN p.peopleName, pl.placeName, e.eventTitle, e.eventDate order by e.eventDate desc
```

Comment: thanks, i already know how to use in where clause but i thought i can use on the same line with Match.